# LinkedIn get people by Id in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, express, linkedin-api

I want to get some data from an API of LinkedIn with Node.js.
I followed this tutorial https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin and I wrote this program that is suposed to send data to the console in the callback.

```
var Linkedin = require('node-linkedin')('XXX', 'XXX', 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/linkedin/callback');
var express = require('express');

var app = express()
    // Initialize 
var scope = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'];


var linkedinVariables = {
    'accessToken': null,
    'client': null
}

app.get('/oauth/linkedin', function(req, res) {
    // This will ask for permisssions etc and redirect to callback url. 
    Linkedin.auth.authorize(res, scope);
});

app.get('/oauth/linkedin/callback', function(req, res) {
    Linkedin.auth.getAccessToken(res, req.query.code, req.query.state, function(err, results) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err);

        console.log(results);

        linkedinVariables.accessToken = results.access_token;

        console.log("ACCESS TOKEN IS ", linkedinVariables.accessToken);

        linkedinVariables.client = Linkedin.init(linkedinVariables.accessToken);

    /*  linkedinVariables.client.people.me(function(err, $in) {
            console.log($in);
        });*/

/*linkedinVariables.client.people.me('linkedin_id', ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name'], function(err, $in) {
    // Loads the profile by id.
    console.log($in);
});*/
        linkedinVariables.client.people.id('HM3nX8nJD6', function(err, $in) {
            console.log($in)
        });
        // return res.redirect('/');
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Now this program works fine and I get the data with this line:

```
linkedinVariables.client.people.me('linkedin_id', ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name'], function(err, $in) {
        // Loads the profile by id.
        console.log($in);
    });
```

which get me a JSON response in my console but following the tutorial I'm suposed to get other informations about companies and people by ID but the response is blank even when I put my own ID to get my own information.
Is there something wrong with my code or is LinkedIn refusing all get requests?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var scope = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_fullprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'r_network', 'r_contactinfo', 'rw_nus', 'rw_groups', 'w_messages'];
```

insted of

```
var scope = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'];
```